# Wifi Adapter not found after update

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, hp, realtek-wireless

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Today after a update (I guess it updated the kernel to 5.3), my wifi is not working. It says the wifi adapter is missing.

I was previously using the repository from lwfinger (https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new), but now the files have been removed, since he says that kernel 5.0 and above have the drivers built in.

Can anyone help me in getting my wifi back either using the built-in drivers or any other way?
I have, I believe a rtl8723 card.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
    Kernel modules: wl
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven Ridge [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] [1002:15dd] (rev c5)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Larry Finger has moved this driver to another branch.
You have an RTL8723DE device, that still needs drivers.

You can install them by

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Comment: It works great! Thanks a lot.